# Will netty automatically flush writed data?

Tags: java, netty

Recently I was writing a http server and I transplanted some netty components to my project. When I read the source code of netty's `ChannelHandlerContext`, I found that actually it doesn't flush into socket. I knew that I have to invoke `flush()` to flush the internal buffer into socket.

So I wonder will netty automatically flush the internal buffer, I have read some source code, but I am not good at it. And I googled but none answered it, the only answer I got is do flushing.

What I have learned from source code is: write continue writing into outboundbuffer, and if outboundbuffer reaches highwatermark, it will fire writability changed event and the channel is unwritable.

Comment: What's wrong with doing the flush yourself? Even if it would not be necessary it does not hurt.

Comment: @Henry  I just want to figure out.  As I said in the question, I am implementing a http server, I have to decide should write be flushed automatically at a certain level. And I think netty's behavior can be something I can learn from.

Comment: Netty uses NIO, and NIO does not have any flush operations to a socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `writeAndFlush` method if you want to do it in one line, but otherwise you need to flush or you data will not go through.

Answer (score 0):

> 

4.0 introduced a new operation called flush() which explicitly flushes the outbound buffer of a Channel, and write() operation does not flush automatically. You can think of this as a `java.io.BufferedOutputStream`, except that it works at message level.

> 

Because of this change, you must be very careful not to forget to call `ctx.flush()` after writing something. Alternatively, you could use a shortcut method `writeAndFlush()`.

I found it at https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#write-does-not-flush-automatically

In fact, I have the similar question at [Why did not call ctx.flush() after ctx.write() is called at Netty user guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843899/why-did-not-call-ctx-flush-after-ctx-write-is-called-at-netty-user-guide/59843976#59843976)

Please contact me if you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't.

However, it could be implemented quite easily.

As you said:

> What I have learned from source code is: write continue writing into
> outboundbuffer, and if outboundbuffer reaches highwatermark, it will
> fire writability changed event and the channel is unwritable.

It's right. and it in fact tells a way to automaticallly flush. Just override `ChannelInboundHandler.channelWritabilityChanged` to call `flush()`.