# Why did not call ctx.flush() after ctx.write() is called at Netty user guide?

Tags: java, netty

In the `netty` Java document says that `so be sure to call flush() once you want to request to flush`, but in this example it says that there is no need to call `ctx.flush()`. But I did not find `flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)` was called as what it said.

```
package io.netty.example.time;

public class TimeEncoder extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
        UnixTime m = (UnixTime) msg;
        ByteBuf encoded = ctx.alloc().buffer(4);
        encoded.writeInt((int)m.value());
        ctx.write(encoded, promise); // (1)
    }
}
```

`Second, we did not call ctx.flush(). There is a separate handler method void flush(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) which is purposed to override the flush() operation.` 
https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-8

Answer (score 1):

The point of buffering is that you "gather" a bunch of data together and send it all at once, because it's roughly as fast to send a lot of data as it is to send a small amount of data (because IO is slow).

This is allocating a 4-byte buffer. If you flushed every 4 bytes, it wouldn't be very efficient.

There will be a flush, somewhere, just not in this particular method.

Comment: If there are 3 bytes at last, will they be sent out?

Comment: I notice that there is `write() does not flush automatically` at New and noteworthy in 4.0.
https://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#write-does-not-flush-automatically